# htaccess with Symfony in subdirectory, cannot hide /web

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, redirect

On the server I have the following structure:

```
public_html
    ->wp
    ->project
        ->app
        ->src
        ->web
```

Where wp is a wordpress website and project is a symfony2 applicatiomn.
The intention is that www.domain.com/project gives me the symfony2 application, where all other urls (without /project) go to the wordpress site.

In order to achive this, I have the following htaccess files:

public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^project.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.project.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web/
    RewriteRule (.*)$ web [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/project/web:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So my application works but there is a redirect to www.domain/com/project/web visible, and that is what I want to hide! Please advice as I seem to lack htaccess knowledge to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to hide the word `web` from the URL of symfony app.

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` file to hide the `web`. I have this `.htaccess` file at the root of my symfony app, in your case it should be in project folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com/project$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com/project$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well when I use example you give, it gives me a Wordpress error page, as /web gets me out of the project folder. So what I tried is:

    RewriteRule (.*) /project/web/$1 [L]

or 

    RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]

Both get me to the Symfony2 directory, and in my log file I get:

    "No route found for "GET /project/""

So somehow it never gets to the web directory....

Comment: did you try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com/project$ [NC,OR]` and `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com/project$` have a look at my updated answer

Comment: When I do that, I just get a directory listing of my project directory. What I do notice is that the request gets picked up by htaccess, but always seems to return /project/.

Comment: Okay one step further: the rewrte rules do get me towards the web directory it seems, but the only thing that Symfony gets is /project/, which of course leads to nothing. After all, the routing starts at /. Suppose I can add /project/ to my main routing, but that would mean I have to adapt stuff like FOSUser routing (as that uses /login for example). What I want is that Symfony only sees /

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you put your Symfony app in subdomain.

Comment: Oh yes a lot easier, if it were only an option for me.